# How to retrieve multiple values of a Xml node in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, xml

Look this Xml

```
<Criteres>
   <TypesOffre>
      <TypeOffre>Appartement</TypeOffre>
      <TypeOffre>Maison</TypeOffre>
   </TypesOffre>
</Criteres>
```

I would like to retrieve the values of TypeOffre node and use them in a JOIN like the following statement

```
SELECT T2.Nom
FROM RechercheOffre T1
     INNER JOIN TypeOffre T2 ON (T1.Xml.value('(/Criteres/TypesOffre/TypeOffre)[1]', 'varchar(max)') = T2.Nom)
```

I can't use the value method because she needs a single instance ...

and the query method returns the values of the Typeoffre node in a single column like this

```
AppartementMaison
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT T2.Nom
FROM RechercheOffre T1
CROSS APPLY T1.Xml.nodes('/Criteres/TypesOffre/TypeOffre') AS CTT(TypeOffre)
WHERE 
  T2.Nom = TypeOffre.value('(.)', 'varchar(50)')
```

You need to use `CROSS APPLY` on the `.nodes()` XQuery function to get a pseudo list of rows of XML, and then you can pull out the individual values from the XML nodes and compare to other bits of your database.

Answer (score 0):

With a JOIN

```
SELECT T2.Nom
FROM RechercheOffre T1
CROSS APPLY T1.Xml.nodes('/Criteres/TypesOffre/TypeOffre') AS CTT(TypeOffre)
INNER JOIN TypeOffre T2 ON (TypeOffre.value('(.)', 'varchar(50)') = T2.Nom)
```

Thank's marc_s